# Is it possible to store a predefined (UIKit,Foundation) object which implements NSCoding to user defaults?

Tags: swift, nscoding, userdefaults

Examples that I have seen online only use custom objects.

Predefined objects by Apple do inherit NSCoding.

If it's possible how would one go about doing this ?

I tried using an extension and overriding the two functions defined in the [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding).

I had no luck.

---

Someone marked this as close because the question was unclear.

let me add more detail. 
Object defined in `MapKit` `MKMapCamera`. Has a few properties, I would like to store this object in user defaults.

Articles like this one do this with custom objects: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: IDK what the relationship between NSCoding and Codable is like, but you could always just extend `MKMapCamera` to conform to Codable, yourself

Comment: The "nshipster" link has all of the information you need to store objects conforming to `NSCoding` into `UserDefaults`. What is it you aren't sure about? What have you tried?

Comment: @rmaddy I tried extending the class and implementing the NSCoding methods but I didn't have any luck. I wanted to see an example of this but all the examples use custom classes.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with NSCoding. `MKMapCamera` already implements everything. You just need to archive/unarchive using `NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Simply skip to that part of the article you linked.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh ok, just to be clear. I can convert this to a Data type and store that into the User Defaults using NSKeyedArchiver. Thank you I was overthinking this

Comment: Yes though UserDefaults may not be the best choice. UserDefaults is for storing simple values and preferences. If you have a bunch of archived data, write it to a file.

Comment: @rmaddy The values stored in that class are doubles so I thought it wouldn't be too heavy. I'll keep that in mind thank you